# How do I conditionally display in React?

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements

I'm working on an app to display the NFL weekly schedule.  The below code works, but how do I conditionally render days?  For example, there's only one week where there are Saturday games.  Also, only Sunday games the last week.

```
return (
<div>
      <h2>Thursday</h2>
      {Thursday.map((teams) => (
        <p>
          Week {weekNo + 1} at {teams.schedule[weekNo].time}: {teams.nickname}{" "}
          vs.
          {teams.schedule[weekNo].opponent}{" "}
        </p>
      ))}

      <h2>Saturday</h2>
      {Saturday.map((teams) => (
        <p>
          Week {weekNo + 1} at {teams.schedule[weekNo].time}: {teams.nickname}{" "}
          vs.
          {teams.schedule[weekNo].opponent}{" "}
        </p>
      ))}

      <h2>Sunday</h2>
      {Sunday.map((teams) => (
        <p>
          Week {weekNo + 1} at {teams.schedule[weekNo].time}: {teams.nickname}{" "}
          vs.
          {teams.schedule[weekNo].opponent}{" "}
        </p>
      ))}
      
      <h2>Monday</h2>
      {Monday.map((teams) => (
        <p>
          Week {weekNo + 1} at {teams.schedule[weekNo].time}: {teams.nickname}{" "}
          vs.
          {teams.schedule[weekNo].opponent}{" "}
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
);
};
```

Comment: See [Conditional Rendering - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h2>Thursday</h2>
      {Thursday.map((teams) => (
        <p>
          Week {weekNo + 1} at {teams.schedule[weekNo].time}: {teams.nickname}{" "}
          vs.
          {teams.schedule[weekNo].opponent}{" "}
        </p>
      ))}
```

Extract it into render function and return `null` when not needed:

```
renderThursday = () => {
  if (!Thursday.length) return null

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Thursday</h2>
      {Thursday.map((teams) => (
        <p>
          Week {weekNo + 1} at {teams.schedule[weekNo].time}: {teams.nickname}{" "}
          vs.
          {teams.schedule[weekNo].opponent}{" "}
        </p>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

Then stack them up in your main `return`:

```
return (
  <div>
    {this.renderThursday()}
    {this.renderSaturday()}
    {this.renderSunday()}
    {this.renderMonday()}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks.  It's working.  I used the first answer with the addition of the React fragment code to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

In your case I would create a functional component to prevent code repeat (this component will return null in case there is no schedule to display, so the component will not render anything)

```
function DaySchedule({day, teams, weekNo}) {
  if (!teams.length) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h2>{day}</h2>
      {teams.map(team => (
        <p>
          {`
            Week ${weekNo + 1} at ${team.schedule[weekNo].time}: 
            ${team.nickname} vs. {team.schedule[weekNo].opponent}
          `}
        </p>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

then you can use the component like this :

```
return (
  <div>
    <DaySchedule day="Thursday" teams={Thursday} weekNo={weekNo}/>
    <DaySchedule day="Saturday" teams={Saturday} weekNo={weekNo}/>
    <DaySchedule day="Sunday" teams={Sunday} weekNo={weekNo}/>
    <DaySchedule day="Monday" teams={Monday} weekNo={weekNo}/>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Boisse Thanks.  I was trying that and was running into problems.  I had the same problem with your code.  The fix is outlined in the next answer.  All it needed was the addition of the React fragment code.

Comment: Boisse It's maddening how the small things cause such problems.